# Client gives an error when accessing WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

Error:

> *Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'ICalculatorDuplex' in the ServiceModel client configuration section.
>   This might be because no configuration file was found for your
>   application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract
>   could be found in the client element.*

reference link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735103.aspx

```
    using System;
    using System.ServiceModel;

    namespace Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples
    {
        // The service contract is defined in generatedClient.cs, generated from the service by the svcutil tool.

        // Define class which implements callback interface of duplex contract

        public class CallbackHandler : ICalculatorDuplexCallback
        {

            public void Equals(double result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Equals({0})", result);
            }

            public void Equation(string eqn)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Equation({0})", eqn);
            }

        }

        class Client
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                // Construct InstanceContext to handle messages on callback interface
                InstanceContext instanceContext = new InstanceContext(new CallbackHandler());

                // Create a client with given client endpoint configuration
                CalculatorDuplexClient client = new CalculatorDuplexClient(instanceContext);

             //   Console.WriteLine("Press to terminate client once the output is displayed.");
              //  Console.WriteLine();

                // Call the AddTo service operation.
                double value = 100.00D;
                client.AddTo(value);

                // Call the SubtractFrom service operation.
                value = 50.00D;
                client.SubtractFrom(value);

                // Call the MultiplyBy service operation.
                value = 17.65D;
                client.MultiplyBy(value);

                // Call the DivideBy service operation.
                value = 2.00D;
                client.DivideBy(value);

                // Complete equation
                client.Clear();

                Console.ReadLine();

                //Closing the client gracefully closes the connection and cleans up resources
                client.Close();
            }

        }
    }
```

Client config :

```
<system.serviceModel>
      <client>
        <endpoint address="http://196.9.200.26:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service"
            binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_ICalculatorDuplex"
            contract="ServiceReference1.ICalculatorDuplex" name="WSDualHttpBinding_ICalculatorDuplex">
          <identity>
            <servicePrincipalName value="host/ln-pun-026.imgpoint.com" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </client>
        <bindings>
            <wsDualHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_ICalculatorDuplex" useDefaultWebProxy="true" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" clientBaseAddress="http://196.9.200.26:8000/myClient/" >
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
                  <security mode="None"/>                  
                </binding>
            </wsDualHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

    </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: You'll need to show us the **client-side config** to be able to diagnose anything! Everything inside the `<system.serviceModel>` section

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: CalculatorDuplexClient client = new CalculatorDuplexClient(instanceContext);
this line gives an error

Comment: I see that the contract name in the config file is ServiceReference1.ICalculatorDuplex.  That seems to be another namespace than the one you are using for your service in the code.  Have you changed the namespace manually after you created the proxy?

Comment: problem is solved guys..simply i have to make this line CalculatorDuplexClient client = new CalculatorDuplexClient(instanceContext); to static